# XOR two Binary Strings c++

Tags: c++, xor, bitwise-xor

I have two strings as follows :

```
STRING1  :        011011110011000

STRING2  :        011001000001000

EXPECTED OUTPUT : 000010110010000
```

However, when i try to XOR them(bit-wise) using the following code, the output is blank.
Code:

```
for(int i = 0; i<15; i++)
 {
    final_key[i] = STRING1[i] ^ STRING2[i]; 
    cout<<" XOR = "<<final_key[i];
 }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are trying to XOR 2 `char` at a time. Try instead:

```
final_key[i] = ((STRING1[i]-'0') ^ (STRING2[i]-'0')) + '0';
```

**Explanation**

Refer to [here](http://ascii.cl/) for ASCII values.

The ASCII value for `'0'` is 48 and the ASCII value of `'1'` is 49. `48 ^ 49` is 1, `48 ^ 48` and `49 ^ 49` is 0. These would return a value of 0 or 1 to a `char`, which would stand for either a `EOF` char (if it is 0) or a `SOH` char (if it is one), neither of which are output correctly.

Thus you would want to convert each `char` into a bit (0 or 1) before conducting the XOR operation. Thus you can subtract `'0'` from each `char` to get the numrical value of the digit, conduct the XOR operation, then add back `'0'` to get a proper output

Comment: Your solution works. I'll accept it as soon as I can. Any explanation(if possible).

Comment: Just thought I'd point out a simplification. Since 48^49 = 1 and 48^48 = 49^49 = 0, it's not actually necessary to subtract `'0'` from each input character. It is only necessary to add `'0'` to the result.

Comment: Yes i just realized that, the other answers also are nifty shortcuts that I had no idea existed.

Answer (score 4):

c++ has `std::bitset<>`

```
#incude <string>
#incude <bitset>
#incude <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string s1 = "010101010101010101";
    std::string s2 = "101010101000001111";

    auto result = std::bitset<32>(s1) ^ std::bitset<32>(s2);
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This code produces the following error :  'result' does not name a type
   auto result = std::bitset<32>(s1) ^ std::bitset<32>(s2);

Comment: have you compiled with the -std=c++11 flag? If not, you'll need to explicitly spell out the return type.

Answer (score 3):

The ASCII values of the characters '0' and '1' are 48 and 49.
To apply an XOR on two characters a,b ∈ { '0', '1' } you may use:

```
char result = std::abs(a - b) + '0';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are Xoring characters.That works but you are storing the result as it is without converting the result into character.

```
string s1="011011110011000";
string s2="011001000001000";
char final_key[15];
for(int i = 0; i<15; i++)
 {
final_key[i] = (s1[i] ^ s2[i])+'0'; //paranthesis is important
cout<<final_key[i];
}
```

You could also check whether `s1[i]` is not equal to `s2[i]`, then result is `1`

```
final_key[i]=(s1[i]!=s2[i]?'1':'0');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string strings_xor(string s, string t) {

string res = "";
for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
    if(s[i] == t[i])
        res += '0';
    else
        res += '1';
}

return res;
}
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better for different sizes of strings. :)

```
string XOR(string a, string b){

    ll la = a.length();
    ll lb = b.length();
    string X;
    X = (la > lb ) ? a : b;

    ll i=(la>lb)?la-1:lb-1, j = (la<lb)?la-1:lb-1,x=(la>lb? la-1:lb-1) ;
    for(;i>=0,j>=0;i--,j--,x--){

        X[x] =  (la>lb)? ( a[i] ^ b[j] )+'0' : ( b[i] ^ a[j] )+'0'; 
    }


    return X;
}
```